# Using Scrapy to crawl a list of urls in a section of the start url

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to do realize a CrawlSpider with Scrapy with the following features.
Basically, my start url contains various list of urls which are divided up in sections. I want to scrape just the urls from a specific section and then crawl them.
In order to do this, I defined my link extractor using restrict_xpaths, in order to isolate the links I want to crawl from the rest. 
However, because of the restrict_xpaths, when the spider tries to crawl a link which is not the start url, it stops, since it does not find any links.
So I tried to add another rule, which is supposed to assure that the links outside the start url get crawled, through the use of deny_domains applied to the start_url. However, this solution is not working.
Can anyone suggest a possible strategy?
Right now my rules are :

```
    rules = {Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=(".//*[@id='mw-content- text']/ul[19]"), ), callback='parse_items', follow=True), 
     Rule(LinkExtractor(deny_domains='...start url...'), callback='parse_items',follow= True),}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining a Set by using {} around the pair of rules. Try making it a tuple with ():

```
 rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=(".//*[@id='mw-content- text']/ul[19]"), ), callback='parse_items', follow=True), 
 Rule(LinkExtractor(deny_domains='...start url...'), callback='parse_items',follow= True),)
```

Beyond that, you might want to pass 'unique=True' to the Rules to make sure that any links back to the "start url" are not followed. See [BaseSgmlLinkExtractor](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#basesgmllinkextractor)

Also, the use of 'parse_items' as a call back to both LinkExtractors is a bit of a smell. Based on your explanation, I can't see that the first extractor would need a callback.... it's just extracting links that should be added to the queue for the Scraper to go fetch, right?

The real scraping for data that you want to use/persist generally happens in the 'parse_items' callback (at least that's the convention used in the docs).

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion solved my problem. It was probably because of the brackets. However, some things seem a bit unclear to me and I would like to understand why this works.
First of all, what does the unique parameter exactly do? In the documentation it talks about duplicate filtering, but I am not sure about what that means.
Secondly, I am not too sure about what happens if you get rid of the callback of the first rule. Basically, what happens when a link which follows the first rule is found??

Comment: The unique flag ensures that a URL is only matched once by the Spider. The callback function is called for each match. The callback function is passed the response associated with requesting the URL: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules

Comment: Now I am ok with the unique flag.
Regarding the missing callback in the first rule, it gets called for each url even though it is not specified??

Comment: Yes I think I got how it works, correct me if I am wrong. Basically, at the beginning just the first rule is matched and the links are followed. Then for each link the rules are evaluated again and the second rule matches the link, so that parse_item is called and the contents crawled.
But by doing so, wouldnt I skip crawling the contents of the homepage of the links??

Comment: Typically you'd use two different callbacks.... one will just return Requests that can be followed, the other will return Items that have been scraped. The docs are pretty clear on this. If you need more I'd suggest posting another question.